# Android Studio - Test - Whats the difference between each run type?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing

How should I run my tests?
What´s the difference between each one?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first run type uses Gradle with Android studio build system and it has been added quite recently.

The second run type uses JUnit. This option is better than the first one if you are using some jUnit test cases classes like:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/AndroidTestCase.html

The third run type uses JUnit framework.

In 95% of cases the first option is the best actually, because the only advantage to use JUnit is to have more support on particular Android's test suite.